# How to pause a videosphere in A-frame?

Tags: javascript, virtual-reality, aframe

I don't want a video controller but pause the video and change its current time in JS, what should I do? I have done a lot of research and tried a lot, but it always says" Cannot read property 'pause' of null".

Comment: Hi Sayakura, welcome to StackOverflow. Please share what you've tried (e.g., code/research). Also, take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

If You have a video in your `<a-assets>`:

```
<a-assets>
   <video id="myvideo">
</a-assets>

<a-videosphere src="#myvideo>
```

then You can call play()/pause() on the video asset, like:

```
document.querySelector("#myvideo").pause();
```

---

If You set Your `a-videosphere src` as a direct link to an .mp4 file, then try to call the functions on the `videosphereElReference.getAttribute('src').pause();`

---

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nnonqbL8/).

Comment: I inserted the code with <script> tags within the <head>tags, but it is not working, the video  will play and stop when it ends,  the console says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pause' of null"

Comment: oh, so all the scripts needed to be in a component! That's why my script doesn't work.. thank you

Comment: @Sayakura You can declare functions out of the component, but it seems neater this way :) hope it will work in Your case

Comment: In reference to the last sentence, I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: entityEl.getAttribute("src").pause is not a function ...